# Animate Vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have ndates*50 array of values for the last 10years (where ndates=10years in days).

Each of the 50 values will change each day.

Ideally I would like to see a 2D plot with the values 1:50 along the x axis and their values on the y axis.

I would then like to change the graph to loop through each date updating the graph accordingly. Obviously is this is done at 24 frames per second (like TV) is will look like an animation.

Ideally I would also like the date to shown at least to indicate which month it is, and to have the ability to slow down or speed up the animation.

Can someone please explain to me, how to do this is Matalb.

Comment: Ideally, you would tell us what you already tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways in which you can accomplish your task:

1. Use a `timer` object with a callback that updates your UI.
2. Run in endless for loop and pause every now and then.
3. Create your movie in offline, using `VideoWriter`, and then show using `movie` command.